# how to save the outcome of the code in pyspark within Databricks as a csv file, how to know the path?

Tags: dataframe, csv, pyspark, path, databricks

I have written a code in Databricks using Pyspark and I need to save the resulting dataframe as csv file. I have created a folder named "Output" under my Workspace and ran this code:

```
      \>\>df.write.csv('dbfs:/Workspace/Users/my_account/Output/myfile')
```

when I take a look to the Output folder I do not find any csv file. Do am I giving the Path wrongly? How I can make this work?

The path that I have given above I copied from the Folder right click and the copy the path option there. Can somebody help me how I can make this work in Databricks? I should  sayI am not the admin so I do not have access to other directories folders except from my workspace

Answer (score 0):

If you use `dbfs:` in the URI, data is written to the Databricks File system, probably to the [DBFS Root](https://docs.databricks.com/en/dbfs/index.html). You can check that data is written using a separate cell with the following command:

```
%fs ls dbfs:/Workspace/Users/my_account/Output/myfile
```

But I think that you intend to write data back to the workspace itself, but it's not the best thing to do as it's not a real file system ([doc](https://docs.databricks.com/en/files/workspace.html)). It will put a lot of pressure on the control plane, and there are some limits on which operations could be performed and file size. If necessary, you can put a file into the workspace after you have written it using DBFS - just do, but check file sizes first:

```
%sh cp /dbfs/Workspace/Users/my_account/Output/myfile/*.csv /Workspace/Users/my_account/Output/myfile/
```